# Arduino nano doesn't connect correctly on boot up

Tags: usb, udev, arduino

I have an Arduino Nano connected to my PC that does some basic home automation stuff, and it works nicely. Except that sometimes on bootup, the USB device isn't connected successfully. Unplugging and plugging it in again fixes the problem. I'm guessing that either the Arduino is in a good state on PC bootup time, or Ubuntu doesn't like the device being plugged in that early.

On the [Arduino forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=263610.0) I didn't get any real help.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 64bit.

([Paste bin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10685241/) of dmesg of USB device not working, and [another](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10687406/) when device has been plugged out and in again (and working). Also [lsusb -t before](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10685254/) and [after and working](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10687399/). Seems the same as when the device is plugged in again.)

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-arduino.rules` file for getting `/dev/ttyArduino0` up. Problem is, it doesn't always come up after boot:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="ttyArduino%n"
```

Update:
Taking a closer look at the dmesg of when it doesn't work I notice the following:

```
[    2.040030] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[    2.224039] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    2.512031] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    2.792014] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[    2.976013] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.260013] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.540013] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[    3.948006] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[    4.124013] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[    4.532007] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 5, error -62
```

Then when I plug the device in again (on same port) and it is detected correctly dmesg reports:

```
[  346.712042] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ohci-pci
[  346.939281] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[  346.939289] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  346.939292] usb 2-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[  346.939295] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  346.939297] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: A8008FYE
[  346.982451] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  346.982742] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  346.983019] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  346.993719] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[  346.996838] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[  346.997061] usb 2-2: Detected FT232RL
[  346.997064] usb 2-2: Number of endpoints 2
[  346.997066] usb 2-2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[  346.997069] usb 2-2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[  346.997071] usb 2-2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[  347.001844] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Have you tried with a delay (of bootup time length) on the Arduino?

Comment: I assume you mean a delay in the Arduino program?  Since the `/dev/ttyArduino0` doesn't come up, I don't think my PC can connect to the nano. (It receives a signal from my PC to toggle a pin.)

Comment: Yes - I don't see your code so I've no idea what it does,  but if it does something that prevents connection them a delay at stay might fix it?